# What is the base case in this algorithm?

Tags: java, algorithm, recursion

I am learning recursion and understanding most of it but this specific one baffles me, it is rather basic but I don't get which statement is the base case, I think it's the print line but obviously could be wrong. I know what the net result is but can't seem to follow how it does it step by step.

Code:

```
private static final String DIGIT_TABLE = "0123456789abcdef";


public static void printIt(long n, int base) {

if(n>=base)
  printIt(n / base, base);
System.out.print(DIGIT_TABLE.charAt((int) n % base));

}
```

Comment: n is reduced by the division for each recursive call until it is less than base. Only then is one digit printed from the table and then all accumulated recursions return, each printing the last digit of the reduced value via the table.

Answer (score 1):

The base case is when `n<base`, or when the remaining number can be represented as a single digit in base `base`.

Here's an example of how the program would execute if the base were 16:

```
n_1: 0x1a5
n_2: 0x1a
n_3: 0x1
****
print n_3 % 16 -> 1
print n_2 % 16 -> a
print n_1 % 16 -> 5
```

At the point marked `****`, the condition evaluates to false, so it doesn't go into infinite recursion.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for the base case or termination condition of the recurrence relation, then try this.

```
public static long printIt(long n, int base) {

        if(n==0 || (base==0 || base==1)) return 0;

        if(n>=base)
            printIt(n / base, base);
        long ln = DIGIT_TABLE.charAt((int) n % base);

        return ln;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In an n-base number system, all the digits from 0-(n-1) can be represented in a single digit notation. For example, in a binary system (2-base), 0 and 1 can be represented as single digit and in a hexadecimal system (16-base), all numbers from 0-15 can be represented as single digit (a=10, b=11...f=15). Your program reduces the long n by dividing it by base till the time it becomes lesser than base and then prints its value in that base-base system. I assume the base here is 16 since your string is till 'f'. This means **your method will print the MSB in hexadecimal representation of n.** Note that if you store all the quotients of 'n/base', you will get the hexadecimal representation reversed.